# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the error on top always for some reason. Here is my code:

index.Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Angular Js</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://rawgit.com/nirus/Angular-Route-Injector/master/dist/routeInjector.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page.Html:

```
Hello World
```

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["ui.route.Injector"])

app.config(function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'page.html'

  })

  .when('/helloUser', {
      template: "ds"

  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  })

})
```

Here is a picture of it!:

[image]

I dont know. I tried a lot of ways to avoid this including trying to go to libraries and copy it but still dosent work. Im spectatiting the problem is with the script tag. But i dont know for sure.

Comment: AFAIK, `$routeProvider` is available from `ngRoute`. Try changing your `"ui.route.Injector"` to `"ngRoute"`. `ui.router` has `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider` if you meant to use those, you'll want to change `"ui.route.Injector"` to `"ui.router"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cBy4RPx1HBTv6wmCcOb). As rgthree mentioned you need to use ng-route with $routeProvider. You'd need to download it or add `<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.js"></script>`. Substitute 1.4.2 for your version of angular.

Comment: don't forget that ui.route.injector needs to be replaced with ngRoute, the module is named ngRoute not ui.route.injector

Comment: Ok i will try that out soon!